# Sharing data between threads of different classes obejcts that don't share similar fields or methods

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea, concurrency, transactions

Context: This is a assignment so i dont want the full solution to it.
I have a server, network and client, transactions and accounts classes. The network, client and server all extend threads.

- Network: The Network class provides the infrastructure to allow the
  client and the server to process the transactions. The client and the
  server need to be connected (using connect()) to the network prior to
  an exchange. The Network class also implements an input buffer
  (inComingPacket[]) and an output buffer (outGoingPacket[]) to
  respectively receive transactions from the client and to return
  updated transactions to the client. The capacity of these buffers are
  10 elements, so the network indicates whether they are full or empty.
- Client: The Client class reads all the transactions from a file (transaction.txt) and
  saves them in an array (transaction[]). A transaction is implemented by the
  Transactions.class.
  Using the send() method of Network class the client transfers the transactions
  to the network input buffer and it yields the cpu in case the network input buffer
  is full.
  Also, using the receive() method of Network class the client retrieves the
  updated transactions from the network output buffer and yields the cpu in case
  the buffer is empty. Each updated transaction received is displayed immediately
  on the console.
- Server: The Server class reads all the accounts from a file (account.txt) and saves
  them in an array (account[]). An account is implemented by the Accounts class.
  Using the transferrIn() method of Network class the server retrieves the
  transactions from the network input buffer and performs the operations
  (withdraw, deposit, query) on the specific accounts. It yields the cpu in case the
  buffer is empty.
  Each updated transaction is transmitted to the network output buffer using the
  transferOut( ) method of Network class and the server yields the cpu in case the
  buffer is full.
- The main Driver class (which is not to be touched):

```
       Network objNetwork = new Network("network");
       objNetwork.start();
       Server objServer = new Server();
       objServer.start();
       Client objClient1 = new Client("sending");
       objClient1.start();
       Client objClient2 = new Client("receiving");
       objClient2.start();
```

Network fields and its constructor

```
    private static int maxNbPackets;
    private static int inputIndexClient, inputIndexServer, outputIndexServer, outputIndexClient;                   /* Network buffer indices for accessing the input buffer (inputIndexClient, outputIndexServer) and output buffer (inputIndexServer, outputIndexClient) */
    private static String clientIP;                            /* IP number of the client application*/
    private static String serverIP;                            /* IP number of the server application */
    private static int portID;                                 /* Port ID of the client application */
    private static String clientConnectionStatus;              /* Client connection status - connected, disconnected, idle */
    private static String serverConnectionStatus;              /* Server connection status - connected, disconnected, idle */
    private static Transactions inComingPacket[];              /* Incoming network buffer */
    private static Transactions outGoingPacket[];              /* Outgoing network buffer */
    private static String inBufferStatus, outBufferStatus;     /* Current status of the network buffers - normal, full, empty */
    private static String networkStatus;  
Network(String context)
      { 
         int i;  
        
         /* Initialization of the network components */
        if (context.equals("network"))
          {
            System.out.println("\n Activating the network ...");
            clientIP = "192.168.2.0";
            serverIP = "216.120.40.10";
            clientConnectionStatus = "idle";
            serverConnectionStatus = "idle";
            portID = 0;
            maxNbPackets = 10;
            inComingPacket = new Transactions[maxNbPackets];
            outGoingPacket = new Transactions[maxNbPackets];
            for (i=0; i < maxNbPackets; i++)
            {   inComingPacket[i] = new Transactions();
                outGoingPacket[i] = new Transactions();
            }
            inBufferStatus = "empty";
            outBufferStatus = "empty";
            inputIndexClient = 0;
            inputIndexServer = 0;
            outputIndexServer = 0;
            outputIndexClient = 0;
            networkStatus = "active";
        }
        else /* Activate network components for client or server */
            System.out.println("\n Activating network components for " + context + "...");
      }
```

Server fields and constructor

```
int numberOfTransactions;         /* Number of transactions handled by the server */
    int numberOfAccounts;             /* Number of accounts stored in the server */
    int maxNbAccounts;                /* maximum number of transactions */
    Transactions transaction;         /* Transaction being processed */
    Network objNetwork;               /* Server object to handle network operations */
    Accounts [] account;
Server()
    {
      System.out.println("\n Initializing the server ...");
      numberOfTransactions = 0;
      numberOfAccounts = 0;
      maxNbAccounts = 100;
      transaction = new Transactions();
      account = new Accounts[maxNbAccounts];
      objNetwork = new Network("server");
      System.out.println("\n Inializing the Accounts database ...");
      initializeAccounts( );
      System.out.println("\n Connecting server to network ...");
      if (!(objNetwork.connect(objNetwork.getServerIP())))
      {
        System.out.println("\n Terminating server application, network unavailable");
        System.exit(0);
      }
    }
```

I wont give the client class because I think you get the idea. My job is essentially to implement the run functions of all these classes. But I don't see how their threads will be able to share data like they need to plus i need to think about concurrency.
Some advice please, sorry its so long.

Comment: Maybe you should tell your teacher that you can't figure out how to start and they should help you. They get paid for that. This question seems too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1) Thread-safe collections like LinkedBlockingQueue etc, 2) PipedInputStream etc

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do some more research and try for yourself some of the online tutorials that show Java concurrency and the area that you are asking about; synchronisation. ie Google search on: 'java concurrency tutorial' and 'java synchronized method'. The reference point: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Some of the examples you should work through to get better understanding are: https://www.javatpoint.com/synchronization-in-java and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html